# Read/Get values from spring application.properties inside camunda bpmn

Tags: spring-boot, bpmn, camunda

How to get/read values from spring appliation.properites inside camunda bpmn script task(groovy).

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Well I guess the easiest way to achieve this is to put the application.properties values you need to access in your process in process variables.

Comment: We already have lot of properties in application.properties so moving them would be difficult but above suggested solution worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example:
https://github.com/rob2universe/camunda7-groovy/blob/a5b224336d93721a633620e4011efc5c69ea0e01/src/main/resources/process.bpmn#L15
using Spring expression language

```
${environment.getProperty('spring.datasource.url')}
```

as a script in parameter.